# Cannot execute sudo command without correct password (Even though my account has no password). Why?

Tags: 14.04, password, sudo, administrator

My account on my computer does not require a password, and I have admin privelages. As I understand it, so I'm trying to run `sudo [...]` and getting the following result when leaving the password field blank

```
user@computer:~$ sudo apt-get install jdk
[sudo] password for user: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for user: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for user: 
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

What do I need to do to run this successfully. Is there a default internal password I'm not aware of?

Running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x32.

Thanks!

Comment: I never lost a password though. I literally never set one.

Comment: that is exactly what the link in my comment answers. You need to set a password for your account to be able to use `sudo`. Without that, sudo is locked and is not accessible.